# Как сделать плавный скролл якоря?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Перепробовал миллион способов, ничего не помогает. Нужно сделать плавный скролл от button до div. Вот код:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#block-1">
  <p class="header-nav nav-1">home</p>
</a>
<a href="#block-2">
  <p class="header-nav">about</p>
</a>
<a href="#block-3">
  <p class="header-nav">work</p>
</a>
<div id="block-1" class="block-2">
  <div id="block-2" class="block-2">
    <div id="block-3" class="block-3">
```

Comment: Если что блоки div закрыты

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012495/smooth-scroll-to-div-id-jquery/26129950

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on("click","a", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var id  = $(this).attr('href'),

  top = $(id).offset().top;
  
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 200);
 });
});
```

```css
.block {
  height:400px;
}
.block_blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.block_red {
  background-color: red;
}
.block_pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#block-1">
  <p class="header-nav nav-1">home</p>
</a>
<a href="#block-2">
  <p class="header-nav">about</p>
</a>
<a href="#block-3">
  <p class="header-nav">work</p>
</a>
<div id="block-1" class="block block_blue"></div>
<div id="block-2" class="block block_red"></div>
<div id="block-3" class="block block_pink"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается у меня была ссылка на не валидную библиотеку jquery, а так код рабочик